# Error 10061 : Connection refused

Tags: linux, centos

The server (CentOS 5) was working fine Until someone deleted some file under the /usr.

Now it shows this error :

Error Code 10061: Connection refused Background: When the gateway or proxy server contacted the upstream (Web) server, the connection was refused. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the upstream server.

What could the possible causes be?

Comment: (BTW, the check mark is for you to use to indicate which answer solved your problem. Once you select one, the problem is considered solved and probably won't get any more answers. You can change or remove it at any time.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It really didnt fix my problem tho. I missused the check for the vote up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection refused means that the web server isn't running. So you go and start it. If you find it doesn't start because it doesn't exist anymore, then you know what got deleted.

Comment: I can connect to the server via ssh.

Comment: Right, that's how you log in to restart the web server, figure out what got deleted, do other admin tasks, etc. :)

Comment: Thank you. Im issuing a yum update and skiping the broken dependencies first. Than i will try to fix the broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

There are literally thousands of files in the /usr directory. If you can figure out what file got deleted you'll be closer to finding your answer.

Check your web server's logs for a better clue. I've seen this when using php-cgi for a web server, and PHP's files are in /usr/bin ...so maybe that's a clue.

Comment: I think it has somehting to do with some packages like libcurl libcurl_devel and php-pspell those were broken. I will try to fix them first.

Comment: Just a suggestion - if you have tons and tons of broken packages an OS reinstall may be in your best interest if it's just a web server. Fixing broken packages is quite a task in itself.

Comment: I think i only had 3 broken packages. Does the yum reinstall work on them?

Comment: It should. Use the -f switch to force it past dependency errors if you need to.